# How to validate phone number in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using the `@valid` annotation for all the validations in a Spring MVC project. I want to validate a phone number, but I can't find a way.

I tried this, but it gives an error that I can't use `@Size` on `int` and `long`.

```
@Size(10)
private long phone;
```

I also tried this, but it gives an error that the maximum value is out of bounds as it can only take values as `int`.

```
@Min(1000000000)
@Max(9999999999)
private long phone;
```

I also tried `regex` in `@Pattern`, but it gives the same error that I can't validate a `@Pattern` as an `int` or a `long`.

```
@Pattern(regex="...")
private long phone;
```

If I don't write any annotations and try to enter an empty string, it gives an error when converting from a string to a long for an empty string, `""`. Is there any way I can validate a phone number without changing it to `String`?

Edit: Yes, I have used `@Valid` and `BindingResult` and I cannot change a phone number to string as it is connected with a database which has `bigint` in the table. Changing it here will affect everything else because I'm using Hibernate for auto saving in SQL.

Comment: why would you store the phone number as a number?

Comment: It's gives error 'cause you're giving integer. Try `@Max(9999999999L)`. But I recommend use string not number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use String and `@Valid` annotation with regex pattern.